# How to manage (ana)conda with pycharm 2016.3 in linux

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, anaconda

I would like to use Anaconda and the newest Pycharm 2016.3 together.  I would like to be able to manage packages in settings->interpreter. If this is not supported, I would like to know the workflow of using these two together. According to another SO question, Pycharm 5 used to have a 'Create conda env' in the interpreter settings, but this seems to be gone now. I have tried:

1) Manually creating a virtual environment with 'conda create --name project numpy' and I add the interpreter ('~/anaconda2/envs/bin/python', the location of python for my created virtual environment.  However, pycharm doesn't allow me to add any packages through settings->interpreter. Running an 'import numpy' through the console shows errors that are pointing to /usr/bin/python, not my virtual env python, and an error 'ImportError: cannot import name multiarray'.  I'm not sure what package to add using conda from the cli, and the pycharm frontend doesn't add packages

2) I've tried the same as 1) but with my global anaconda python as the interpeter ('~/anaconda2/bin/python') and it doesn't seem to be able to connect to the console.

3) Creating a virtual environment through pycharm directly.

I would like to remove my default pythons (/usr/bin/python2.7/3.5 from the list of interpreters in pycharm) for debugging purposes but it won't let me and it seems to be showing packages that my anaconda virtual env doens't have installed.

Is there a way to manage my VIRTUAL enviornment in Conda using pycharm? If not, what steps do I take to make these two play well together assuming I can't manage it through pycharm interepreters settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal steps that i follow when i use virutalenv with PyCharm

I normally work on ubuntu

- First, i always create a separate environment for every project using the command `virtualenv "environment_name"` from the command line.
- Activate the environment using the command - `source environment_name/bin/activate` in ubuntu.
- Suppose if i want to start a django project, i create the project using the command `django-admin startproject project_name`
- Open this project in pycharm.
- go to settings-> interpreter in pycharm. choose "add local" interpreter from the settings. It will open a pop-up. Go to the directory of the environment you just created and select the correct python interpreter you want to use.
- now if you want to install a new package, you can go to interpreter settings and add package from the pycharm or you can fire up the command line, activate the environment and run `pip install package_name`. Once the package is installed, it will also show in pycharm.
- if you are using Windows OS, use powershell to execute the above commands. The only difference will be in activating the environment. In windows, to activate an env use `environment_name/Scripts/activate`

EDIT:
Same goes anaconda environments also, the easy way is to manage the environment from the terminal and pycharm will show the packages changes in the interpreter settings.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Yaman, but anaconda doesn't use the 'virtualenv' command. Conda uses it's own manager 'conda create/list, source activate <env>'.  I believe this is key, because although Pycharm has ability to create vitual environments (using 'create Virtual env'), it doesn't work well (I think) with conda virtual envs. My next attempt will be to try and manage all env with conda cli, but pycharm still has to point to the right interpreter and irks me when it shows the wrong packages/version well see if I can get past my 'cannot import name multiarray' in pycharm using conda cli

Comment: that's correct. You can also use `conda create env_name` and add the interpreter in pycharm as a local interpreter. Here is link written by anconda guys to use conda interpreter in Pycharm.

Comment: So I've gone so far as to rename my /usr/bin/python2.7 and 3.5 executables to remove them from the list in pycharm. So now the local interepreter is ~/anaconda2/envs/<project>/bin/python.  The package list shows some packages that are not shown with either 'conda list' or 'conda list -n <project>'. conda update --all shows all updated, pycharm shows lots of packages that need updating, when I try and update through pycharm it says the package isnt installed.

Comment: It appears as if it has found many packages in anaconda global ('~/anaconda2/bin/') and and some I don't know where they come from, and many that need updating.

Comment: better option is to use terminal when updating or downloading new packages

Comment: Yes I saw that but it's pointing to the global anaconda python not the VIRTUAL env. In fact the page doesn't mention the virtual env python bin at all.   I am making progress however.  After running the vitual env from the command line and running 'import sys; '\n'.join(sys.path)'  I saw that I had .local/lib/... python libraries in my path.  I deleted .local and now pycharm and the conda virtual env are consistent.  I still cant do any installing through pycharm, but if necessary i can manage with conda cli

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have been doing and it works great. I create a virtual environment separately and when I create a new project in PyCharm, I point the interpreter to the python from the virtual environment. An example is shown in the picture below:

[image]